# mongoose find with filter on enum not returning results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema as given below;

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    //...
    pets: {type: String, enum: ["Cat", "Dog", "Bird", "Snake"]}
    //...
});

// create a new user
const user = new User({
    fullname, email, pets:"Cat"
});
try {
    await user.save();
    res.send({ "success": true, user});
} catch (err) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: "Could not add User!", error: err });
}

// to fetch users
const users = await User.find({pets:'Cat'});
res.json({ 'success': true, users });
```

The response is always empty users array while i have data in db of users having pets value as Cat

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": []
}
```

Can someone please guide me what's wrong here? or how to get the results with pet as Cat?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating new users?

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois, i have updated the code for creating a new user

Comment: That's weird. It looks ok. I even tested it myself directly in mongodb to be sure the query is fine. What does the user document look like? The queries are case sensitive. Are you 100% sure you're querying for 'C', and that the document has pets stored with 'C'?

Comment: @StephanBakkelundValois yes, the document has pets stored with 'C', let me check once again

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with data, i dropped the collection and it started working.